# How to do a elasticsearch aggregation for the last N items in the index

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

Giving we had an time sequence index, how do we run an aggregate only on the last N items in the index ?

Answer (score 0):

In a time sequence index, you can sort the result based on `datetime` field (field storing the index time info) in descending order and limit the number of results using `size` option in search query and run `aggs` on top of thee result.

The `datetime` field can be `_timestamp` field if you are using elasticsearch version <2.0. In later versions of elasticsearch, you have to explicitly add a datetime field in the mapping and set its value when you are indexing.

In short, change the search query so that the last N results become the first N results and execute aggregation on the result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": N,
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateTimeFieldName(May be _timestamp)": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  'aggs': {
     <your aggregation query>
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we tried this way, but it's not working. The size affected the 'hits' return in the result, but no effects on the aggregations result.